# Error when deleting Scheduled task during Uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, scheduled-tasks, installshield

In my installer, I have a .NET installer class assembly which adds a Scheduled task to Windows Task Scheduler in its AfterInstall event handler and deletes the scheduled task in its BeforeUninstall event handler.

My Scheduled task runs an exe every 1 sec. During uninstall, if my exe is running then the installer shows below message

[image]

To avoid this message I initially planned to add a custom action that disables my scheduled task and deletes the current instance of the exe but this requires administrative permissions and I've also read that all the custom actions that require administrative permissions should be sequenced after **InstallFinalize** stage of windows installer. It means that even if I implement the custom action I would still get the above error message since the check for whether files are locked happens in **InstallValidate** stage which is sequenced before **InstallFinalize**

So, is there any other way to avoid the above error message that I'm getting during uninstall?

My installer is basic MSI type and I created it using InstallShield

Comment: Before trying to answer this, could you please review this: [Service vs Task Scheduler](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#ServiceVsTaskScheduler). I would use a service if I ran as frequently as you describe?

Comment: "all the custom actions that require administrative permissions should be sequenced after InstallFinalize stage of windows installer." - nope.  They should be sequenced between InstallIntialize and InstallFinalize.  What context does the exe run in (user/system?).  Could you run a TASKKILL.exe via a custom action before InstallValidate if it's running in a user context?

Comment: The exe runs in System context

Comment: Perhaps just set the property MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL to 'disable' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msirestartmanagercontrol) and then kill the process shortly after InstallInitialize via a Custom Action or otherwise?